# Cakephp: Get data from model into another models's View

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In a Cakephp v2.3 App, there are two models:

**Purchase Model**: it contains the following main fields: id, invoice_date & gross_amount(calculated on Supplier.tax_rate).

```
class Purchase extends AppModel {

    public $displayField = 'id';
    public $belongsTo = 'Supplier';
}
```

**Supplier Model**: it contains id, name & tax_rate

```
class Supplier extends AppModel {
    public $displayField = 'name';
    public $hasMany = 'Purchase';
}
```

This is how my Add view of PurchasesController Looks:
[image]

Now, I want to get `Supplier.tax_rate` of currently selected supplier displayed In `app/View/Purchase/add.ctp` as label or text input.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Maybe You can launch an ajax call to retrieve the data from supplier with an onChange event on the select option.. what do you think?

Comment: Yes, but Instead I ended putting all data into view because supplier data was under 5kb, so it made sense to output all data into the view as JSON as once which would help avoid latency.each ajax call would have have added to latency :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. 
What, I ended up doing was putting all supplier tax rate data as `JSON`, outputting that into the view & then using client-side javascript to select the relevant code.

PurchasesController calls a custom model method which fires up a SQL query to get all supplier tax rate data.

```
$supplier_tax_rate = $this->Purchase->Supplier->getTaxRate();
$this->set('supplier_tax_rate', json_encode($supplier_tax_rate));
```

The, in the client-side. I used Javascript to do what I wanted, here `supplier_tax_rates` is the variable which stored JSON tax rate data & `getTaxRate` is a variable function which returns tax rate from JSON based on `id` from supplier downdown.

```
$(function() {
    var taxRates = $.parseJSON(supplier_tax_rates);

    var getTaxRate = function(id) {
        for (var i in taxRates) {
            if (taxRates[i].id == id) {
                return taxRates[i].tax_percentage_charged;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

This has worked nicely for me, Hope it helps other people who want to get some data from database in cake, based on the value of dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery to lookup the tax rate on change of the select box. Look up JsHelper, http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html for more details

Here is some example view code that comes from one of my 1.3 apps that may help you. You of course have to have the helper, jquery, controller code and other view to load in.

```
//helper in view
//observe selectbox for selection, if change, update question.
$js->get('#EntitiesUserPrimarycontactId')->event('change', $js->request(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'update_previewcontact'),array('update'=>'#step4_results','dataExpression'=>true,
'before' => "$('#step4_results').fadeOut('fast');",
'complete' => "$('#step4_results').fadeIn('slow');,
'data'=>$js->serializeForm(array('isForm' => true, 'inline' => true)) )));
```

Comment: I tried this but I couldn't get this to work for me but I ended up writing JS by hand instead of having cake generate it for me.